# How to dispose PSObject

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

As shown in the code below I end up creating a new PSObject for each site in the sites collection. Eventually I need to run this for multiple SharePoint web applications each containing several sites, with the total sites crossing 2000. So that is a lot of PSObjects being created.

The PSObject does not have a dispose function so what are my options to make the code more efficient and dispose the object.

Also each time i execute the operation `$SiteInfoCollection += $object` there is reallocation of memory since it is a dynamic expanding array. According to some article i read several months ago any operation of memory reallocation is expensive and not good for performance. Is there a way to make this step efficient as well?

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://portal.contoso.com"

$SiteInfoCollection = @()

foreach($site in $SPWebApp.sites)
    {
        $object = New-Object PSObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name URL -Value ""
        Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Title -Value ""
        Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Template -Value ""

        $object.url = $site.url
        $object.title = $site.rootweb.title
        $object.template = $site.rootweb.WebTemplate

        $SiteInfoCollection += $object

        #$object.Dispose() #NOT valid operation
    }
    $site.Dispose()
}
$SiteInfoCollection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This object will be garbage collected when it's time to do so. It's not a heavy SharePoint object that contains COM & Database connections and there for doesn't need to be disposed.

You **want** to dispose $site so put in inside the foreach loop.

For most SharePoint PowerShell command you can use `-AssignmentCollections` instead of manually disposing:

> Manages objects for the purpose of proper disposal. Use of objects, such as SPWeb or SPSite, can use large amounts of memory and use of these objects in Windows PowerShell scripts requires proper memory management. Using the SPAssignment object, you can assign objects to a variable and dispose of the objects after they are needed to free up memory. When SPWeb, SPSite, or SPSiteAdministration objects are used, the objects are automatically disposed of if an assignment collection or the Global parameter is not used.

A more PowerShell way to get the same functionallity would be

```
$gc = Start-SPAssignment
Get-SPSite "http://portal.contoso.com" -Limit All -AssignmentCollection $gc | % {
    # Loop
}
Stop-SPAssignment -Identity $gc
```

Comment: `Get-SPSite` returns a collection of individual `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite` objects. `$SPWebApp.Sites` returns `Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection` which i think is not as memory intensive as the former. The foreach loop creates only 1 SPSite object which is used to get the properties for each SPSite in the collection. That is why i call Dispose outside the foreach loop. However this is my current understanding and I could be wrong. Also so far I have been using Start and Stop SPAssignment at the start and end of my scripts. My aim is to make my scripts more efficient.

Comment: You mentioned about PSObject not being a "heavy" object like a SharePoint object which makes sense now. But does that mean we do not always need to "dispose" all objects created? As a system admin I am not very clear on these programming concepts.

Comment: @Ron powershell automatically gets rid of all created objects as soon as the runspace is closed

Comment: @Paul Just because PowerShell gets rid of objects when the runspace is closed doesn't mean disposal is unnecessary. If you have a script that works with a lot of objects, you may still find that it's wise to dispose to avoid hogging memory.